# Swift 3.0-Switch statement without default statement getting error 'Switch must be exhaustive, consider adding default clause'

Tags: switch-statement, swift3

Following is the code used for executing Switch statement in playground. I executed few switch statements without using default. My doubt is why it is optional for some and mandatory for other statements.Thanks in advance!.

```
let someNumber = 3.5

switch someNumber {

case 2 , 3 , 5 , 7 , 11 , 13 :
  print("Prime numbers")
case 4 , 6 , 24 , 12 , 66 :
  print("Normal numbers")

 }
```

Counter statement executed successfully without using default

```
  let yetAnotherPoint = (3,1)

  switch yetAnotherPoint {

  case let (x,y) where x == y :
   print("(\(x),\(y)) is on the line x == y")
  case let (x,y) where x == -y :
   print("(\(x),\(y)) is on the line x == -y")
  case let (x,y):
   print("(\(x),\(y)) is just some arbitrary point")

   }
```

Comment: You are required to cover every possible case in Swift.  So it wants you to add something like: `default: print("Some other number")`

Comment: I executed few switch statements without using default. My doubt is why in this particular statement error message is triggered making default as mandatory.

Comment: The error message is clear. Every value that goes through a switch must be acted upon by either a case or a default clause. If you have a counter example, please show it.

Comment: At a minimum, add `default: break` to this example if you'd really just want to skip all of the other numbers.

Comment: Your second example covers every possible case. No point can get through there without being handled. You could have also achieved that in your first switch with `case let x: print("\(x) is some unknown number")`

Comment: `consider adding default` does not mean `you must add default`.  It just means, this is an easy way to meet the requirement of handling every possible case.

Comment: Any suggestion if possible. What needs to be done for the first switch statement so that it covers every possible case without making default as mandatory for executing the code.

Comment: I gave you such a suggestion in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As other stated in comments, you should use `default` because in your cases you're not exposing every possible Double. But if you like more the way you did it in your second example you could do it like so:

```
let someNumber = 3.5
switch someNumber {
case 2 , 3 , 5 , 7 , 11 , 13 :
    print("Prime numbers")
case 4 , 6 , 24 , 12 , 66 :
    print("Normal numbers")
case let x:
    print("I also have this x = \(x)")
}
```

Just for the reference, here's how this scenario is most often handled:

```
let someNumber = 3.5
switch someNumber {
case 2 , 3 , 5 , 7 , 11 , 13 :
    print("Prime numbers")
case 4 , 6 , 24 , 12 , 66 :
    print("Normal numbers")
default:
    print("I have an unexpected case.")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
            default:
            1 == 1
```

God knows why you need a default.